# touch event do not work when clicked on recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

When I Override the method `onTouchEvent()`, it worked well when touching every place on the screen but when I touch above `RecyclerView`, it did not been called.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    int action = event.getActionMasked();
    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.d(TAG, "Action was DOWN");
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d(TAG, "Action was UP");
            break;
     }
}
```

Comment: are you using dispatch event ?

Comment: If you have empty recycler it should work, but if there are items, you have to override onTouchEvent for item.

Comment: the recyclerview it empty and didn't work

Comment: Are you set the `setOnTouchListener(this)` on `recyclerView`?

Comment: I didn't set setOnTouchListener on recyclerView

Comment: when i use dispatchTouchEvent instead of onTouchEvent it worked but all buttons clicks stopped.

Comment: @sy4tech please set the `TouchListener` on `recyclerview` [URL](https://guides.codepath.com/android/gestures-and-touch-events).